# Windows 7 tilde key issue

Tags: windows-7

Hey, I'm working on windows 7 and my tilde key only works after pressing it for about 2 seconds. What can I do about it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tilde is a dead key, try switching your keyboard lay-out to one not using dead keys.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is not a hardware fault? Keyboards do break, and it is quite possible that a single switch has almost failed.

Comment: I'm sure. I tried another keyboard.

Answer (score -1):

There is something funky going on here with adding the United States-International keyboard. After adding the keyboard, the tilde and the back-quote key only work by holding them down long enough to get them to repeat. Removing the United States-International keyboard fixes the problem but then, of course you no longer have the additional keyboard.

If anybody has a fix for this, let us know.

And, no, this is not just in a game, this is in all apps - UltraEdit, browsers, email, etc....

Comment: Don't put questions as answers!  This question, luckily for you, [has already been asked and answered](http://superuser.com/questions/288003/).