# When I type " nothing comes out, and if I type it again, 2 of it comes out as such: ""

Tags: windows, keyboard

Something is wrong with my keyboard : when I type <kbd>"</kbd>, nothing comes out, and if I type it again, 2 of them come out as such: `""`.

Same goes with the <kbd>'</kbd> key. The first time I type it, nothing comes out, then if I hit it again two of them appear (so I have to backspace one of them everytime).

I've got no idea what I did to my computer, it was working properly yesterday. (I think I was messing around with the language thing, however I've just undid everything I've did and its still not working.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apostrophes and double quotes don't show up until I type the next letter](https://superuser.com/questions/122625/apostrophes-and-double-quotes-dont-show-up-until-i-type-the-next-letter)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your keyboard at all.  You've selected a keyboard layout that has [dead key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964658#Dead_key) support on those keys.  One such layout is US International, for example.  Microsoft has [a rather confusing table of all of the extra characters that you can type on your keyboard with these layouts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195156.aspx).  (It tells one the Unicode code points for the characters, but only hints at the actual key combinations to use to make them.)

Microsoft also provides the [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665), for people to create their own customized layouts as they did in response to [this SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/280005/), and [some pictures of layouts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688179).

Comment: Facing the same issue, any tips on which is a "Normal" keyboard layout?