# Why do I have to press the key 4 times to get a '`' symbol?

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using Windows 8.1 Pro, with a Microsoft Gaming keyboard. When I'm writing posts on StackOverflow I often need to enclose things in code marks (`). In order to get these, I have to press the <kbd>¬ |</kbd> key on my keyboard 4 times, which produces two of these.

[image]

Why do I need to do this? Why doesn't this key work as others?

Comment: Stupid question but have you tried another keyboard? I am using 8.1 with a cheap Dell keyboard and see no problem.

Comment: Just plugged in a cheap Dell keyboard (everyone's got one, right?) and had the same issue - 4 key presses required before anything appears

Comment: OK so its software not hardware. Small possibility of virus/malware more likely somehting is trying to "help" you like a manufacture supplied background utility. Try disabling startup tasks and also see if it happens in Safe mode.

Comment: Covers the same ground as http://superuser.com/questions/288003/ and http://superuser.com/questions/122625/ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an International keyboard layout set for your keyboard (probably United States-International keyboard layout - but there are others).

With this keyboard layout the <kbd>`</kbd> keystroke becomes a modifier to enable entering of special characters.

To get a single <kbd>`</kbd> character you will need to type <kbd>`</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

Alternatively change the keyboard layout to the appropriate non-international version.

See [Add a keyboard layout](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/change-keyboard-layout) for more information.

---

> Type International and Special Characters using the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key or the following modifier keys: Apostrophe(<kbd>'</kbd>), Accent Grave(<kbd>`</kbd>), Quotation Mark(<kbd>"</kbd>), Tilde(<kbd>~</kbd>), and Circumflex(<kbd>^</kbd>). To type just the modifier key by itself, type <kbd>Space</kbd> following the modifier key.

Source [Help with Microsoft Keyboards US-International | School of Languages, Cultures, and Race | Washington State University](https://slcr.wsu.edu/help-pages/microsoft-keyboards-us-international/)

Answer (score 0):

Those are [dead keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key) used to modify certain letters. You may want to change keyboard layout to get rid of this behavior.

---

Edit: see post [here](https://superuser.com/questions/280005/how-to-make-and-non-dead-keys-on-windows-7-with-german-keyboard-layout)